# Unexpected parser rule matching order

Tags: antlr, antlr4

With the following (subset of a) grammer for a scripting language:

```
expr
    ...
    | 'regex(' str=expr ',' re=expr ')'  #regexExpr
    ...
```

an expression like `regex('s', 're')` parses to the following tree which makes sense:

```
regexExpr
   'regex('
   expr: stringLiteral ('s')
   ','
   expr: stringLiteral ('re')
   ')'
```

I'm now trying to add an option third argument to my regex function, so I've used this modified rule:

```
'regex(' str=expr ',' re=expr (',' n=expr )? ')'
```

This causes `regex('s', 're', 1)` to be parsed in a way that's unexpected to me:

```
regexExpr
   'regex('
   expr:listExpression
      expr: stringLiteral ('s') 
      ','
      expr: stringLiteral ('re')
   ','
   expr: integerLiteral(1)
   ')'
```

where `listExpression` is another rule defined below `regexExpr`:

```
expr
    ...
    | 'regex(' str=expr ',' re=expr (',' n=expr)? ')' #regexExpr
    ...
    | left=expr ',' right=expr                        #listExpr
    ...
```

I think this `listExpr` could have been defined better (by defining surrounding tokens), but I've got compatibility concerns with changing it now.

I don't understand the parser rule matching precedence here. Is there a way I can add the optional third arg to `regex()` without causing the first two args to be parsed as a `listExpr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining them in two separate alternatives and with the same label `#regexExpr`:

```
expr
 : 'regex' '(' str=expr ',' re=expr ',' n=expr ')' #regexExpr
 | 'regex' '(' str=expr ',' re=expr ')'            #regexExpr
 | left=expr ',' right=expr                        #listExpr
 | ...
 ;
```

Comment: Interesting. The breaking up of `regex` and `(` seemed to be what made it work. The above without that break-up still matches the undesirable way. Thanks.